# How to run 32-bit applications on 64-bit Slackware?

Tags: 64bit, slackware

I used to use Slamd64 before, and it was easy. It came with all 32-bit libraries as well. Since official 64-bit Slackware is released, Slamd64 is no longer maintained. However, Slackware seems to be pure 64bit, so I cannot run 32bit apps. I searched the net and found some instructions, but they all require that I install some package manager (slapt-get, whatever). I'd like to do it without messing too much with the system. Where should I start?

Answer (score 1):

It's all in this readme:
http://connie.slackware.com/~alien/multilib/

Simply follow instructions from the README:

- download the package directory corresponding to your Slackware version.
- upgrade (replaces the existing 64 bits version) glibc and gcc to the multilib version
- install the 32 bit compatibility package
- preferably, reboot (glibc upgrade)

Now you may install existing 32 bit packages or  compile 32 bit programs.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. Please don't answer with just a link, include at least the essential information directly in your answers. See [answer].

Comment: @Gilles, in that case the OP didn't really do his homework, I could almost have linked to lmgtfy.com :) What use is it to copy and paste the readme in my post?

Comment: Which instructions? The part about installing multilib GCC isn't necessary to just _run_ 32-bit apps on a 64-bit machine, is it?

Comment: @Geremia Slackware doesn't manage dependencies. You may try to install multilib libc and keep the 64  bits only gcc, but it may make your gcc unusable. I advise against it, but hey, that's your system :)